# How to connect and run Node.js and React Native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, ubuntu

I am working on an old project where I worked with Node.js and created a frontend using HTML/CSS. I've gone back to it now because I'm in the process of learning React Native. So basically I was going to replace the HTML/CSS with React Native. I have a directory, with one file as the application(react native) and one as the server(Node.js), but I'm not sure how to `npm start` (run) them at the same time. Is this where something like Docker comes in or could I do something like in here: [Setup React and Node.js](https://www.codementor.io/@kakarganpat/how-to-setup-react-and-node-js-in-a-project-koxwqbssl)?

Comment: React and React Native are different frameworks. React is for web and React Native iOS and android

Answer (score 0):

There can be several options to do what you want to achieve.

- Using 2 docker containers (one for the server and one for the client being served by its own server).
- By following the instructions on the link you posted (I didn't tried it but it looks reasonable).
- Use your server to serve your React app as static content ([example](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-render-react-app-using-express-server-in-node-js-a428ec4dfe2b)).
- There is probably other options I didn't think of.

**Warning:** As stated by Michael, React and React Native are two very similar but different frameworks. The first one is web-oriented and will render HTML, the second one is mobile oriented (but you can also target Mac or Windows and even the web with some additional libraries). Since React Native don't render HTML but a native app, you don't need and can't serve this app with a web server so in this case your question is quite a non-sense for me. If you're using React Native, just install the app on your phone and run the server on your computer, you should be able to access it via your local network.

Comment: Do you mean that I should publish it on expo cli and then just use the link to run the app and then just run the (nodejs) server on my computer?

Comment: Yes, something like this seems perfectly fine to me. And then you can connect to your server using the ip of your computer on your local netwrok (often something like 192.168.1.x).